# Can not access value of props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I was console logging the `this.props` from the render function-
[image]
 And in the console I can see these-[image: The props I see..]

However, when I try to access any one of them, say I wanted to access the `store` object, then if log like this `console.log(this.props.store)`. Like this-
[image]
 Then I get this-
[image]

I have no clue what so ever I am doing wrong. If anyone knows what I am doing wrong, please let me know. Any help is appreciated!

The whole code-

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import mapStateToProps from './utilities/mapStateToProp';
//tslint:disable
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props: any){
    super(props);

  }

  public render() {
    console.log(this.props);

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>React + TypeScript = {}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

Comment: Don't use images of code in your question. Paste the actual text, so that we can try your code easily.

Comment: This seems to be a typescript failure, maybe you should validate that the props have the correct definition?

Comment: Okay I am giving the whole codes.....

Answer (score 0):

Save them in your component **state** in your **constructor** and access them from there.

```
constructo(props){
  super(props)
  this.state = { store: props.store }
}
```

And in your **render()**

```
render(){
   const { store } = this.state //use the store const to access to your value
   console.log(store);
}
```

**EDITED**

About not using stateless component you should declare an interface in your component in order your component understand what kind of props has the state, review this link for more information [Typescript and React](https://charleslbryant.gitbooks.io/hello-react-and-typescript/content/TypeScriptAndReact.html)

```
interface IMyComponentProps {
   someDefaultValue: string
}

interface IMyComponentState {
    store: any //dont know what type is your store.
}


class App extends React.Component<IMyComponentProps, IMyComponentState> {
  // ...
}
```

To test a workaround to check if it works try this `React.Component<{},any>`

Comment: I really don't think that is a good idea. Because the whole point of setting up Redux was to not use Stateful Components. (Because in Stateful Components all the states are scattered around in many components)